# Any open source Java Decompiler for Windows 7

Tags: java, decompiling

I am looking for free open source java decompilers. Any suggestions?

We are using Windows 7

I found out that `Dcompiler` is open source, and downloadeded it. (It has come as a RAR file, nothing is there in it except its class files) .

Could you please suggest one which is a open source?

Comment: http://aegif-labo.blogspot.jp/2013/03/what-is-best-open-source-java-decompiler.html

Comment: Are you still looking for open source decompilers? I've written one that's available on Github.

Comment: [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler), [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) (Antimony's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/
- http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: second link is broken

Comment: you are right. There is something wrong with their server now...you can download from here as well http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JD-GUI.shtml

Comment: I fear that "java.decompiler.free.fr" is definitely closed. I've updated the list of miroires this page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler. Try this link : http://jd.benow.ca

Comment: This seems good http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler

Answer (score 1):

It's not open source but it's free:

[DJ JAVA Decompiler](http://downloads.phpnuke.org/en/download-item-view-g-v-v-g-v/DJ+JAVA+DECOMPILER.htm)

Here is one more and it is Open Source. I found it on SourceForge.net

http://jdec.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Prashant ,thank you but  DJ Java Compiler is  Not freeware anymore - License: Free to try; $19.99 to buy.

Comment: Have you tried jdec at sourceforge.net? It's open source

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a tool to decompile or looking to learn how to write one yourself?

If you are just looking for a decompiler that works and is free then I strongly recommend the decompiler here, which I use professionally on a regular basis : http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I just published a stand-alone Java Decompiler GUI (based on Jad) which you can get from Util [Java Decompiler (JAD based) v1.0](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/util-java-decompiler-jad-based-v10exe.html)

This is a Windows based .NET 4.0 application, which supports the drag n'drop of *.jar files.

Comment: Off-topic, asker asked for an open source tool