# Program to decompile jar or class files

Tags: java, decompiler

I am looking to decompile either a complete `.jar` file or simply `.class` files.

I have been googleing around for about an hour now and havnt seem to find any tools to help me.

Most of the tools i found was either outdated or did not work.

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) from stackoverflow but sadly all of the programs suggested can either not be downloaded or is out dated.

Comment: `Jad Gui` - Neither outdated and it can be downloaded from here: https://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Did you see this thread ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753070/any-open-source-java-decompiler-for-windows-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you have many alternatives: http://www.showmycode.com/ .

In practice, I have found [JAD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JAD.shtml) to be closely precise. [JD-GUI](https://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&can=2&q=) is again quite good with eclipse like code viewer.

---

**Edit (2015)**: [Fernflower](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2029842) has picked up quite some hype over last couple of years. Personally I find it to be the best. IntelliJ uses it as default from Idea13 onwards (This speaks volumes as intellij is considered cutting edge as per tooling in java world is concerned). Easiest way to use fernflower would be to drag drop .class files on intellij. In case you wish to use it from command line, then this [might](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower) help.

Answer (score 1):

`.jar` files are just `.zip` files with some specific metadata files (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`), so they can be opened with any unzip program. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29 for more info)

for the `.class` files therein, see this other question: [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Comment: oops. i didn't see that he had referenced the other SO post. still, it's worth looking at, as some answers *do* claim to be applicable to java 1.7